# Метрика для телеграм-бота (сбор статистики)

Tags: telegram-bot, любой-язык, telegram, yandex-metrika-api

Требуется обложить метрикой бота для телеграм. Нашел сайт http://botan.io и не понимаю, жив ли проект... Актуален ли сегодня проект botan.io? У ресурса в футере указан 2015 год. И есть ли альтернатива?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Увы - проект мёртв, как это можно понять [по активности его репозитория на гитхабе](https://github.com/botanio/sdk/issues/85#issuecomment-277649975).

> В декабре написал разработчикам. Сказали, что проект на данный момент
>   не поддерживают, поэтому даже в pull request нет смысла. По датам
>   возобновления работы над сервисом не сказали.

Неизвестно, что именно послужило причиной сворачивания, но у проекта были проблемы с роскомнадзором и блокировками. Альтернатив не нашёл, к сожалению. С удовольствием премирую того, кто предложит адекватную альтернативу.

---

**UPD**

У меня две хорошие новости:

1. Апи ботана работает
2. Можно пользоваться апи ботана с токеном, полученным непосредственно в метрике (проверено опытным путём)

Для бота будет актуальным, думаю, только один метод - `track`. Для этого можно юзать обычные нативные веб-запросы, без обёрток - никаких зависимостей от конкретных реализаций.

**Пример запроса:**

```
// token = qwerty;
// chatID = 12345;
// command = 'start';

https://api.botan.io/track?token=token&uid=chatID&name=command
```

где:

- *token* - токен приложения, выданный метрикой (или ботом, если это настолько старый токен);
- *uid* - идентификатор, позволяющий разделить источники событий или наоборот, сгруппировать их (может быть любым уникальным значением, да даже и не уникальным - на усмотрение разработчика);
- *name* - наименование (произвольное) отслеживаемого действия пользователя

[Track message](https://chatbase.com) <sub>(метод *Shorten url* не работоспособен на территории РФ по причине блокировки домена, возвращающего "*короткие*" ссылки)</sub>

---

**Возможные альтернативы:**

- [chatbase.com](https://chatbase.com)
- [botanalytics.co](https://botanalytics.co/)
- [dashbot.io](https://www.dashbot.io/)
- [botlytics.co](http://www.botlytics.co)

Comment: А почему никто не делает форк, если библиотека такая хорошая? Например, кто-нибудь из Европы или стран СНГ. Спрашиваю из любопытства.

Comment: @DaemonHK проблему это наверное не решит, поскольку этот проект на гитхабе - всего лишь обёртка для апи аналитики [AppMetrika](https://bitbucket.org/pharmanet/olekstracloudnet/commits/1cc909dc14687b27992a1ea913c70a808278b4fe). Для подключения к системе нужен токен, раньше его выдавал бот, который уже не работает. Не знаю, будет ли действителен токен при регистрации приложения непосредственно на сайте

Comment: можно, конечно попробовать работать с апи другими представленными способами, но сам не пробовал разбираться - возможно ваш вопрос меня подтолкнёт к этому )